# Create NSPopUpButton dynamically with external Source (amount of items)

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

Lets say I have a Txt-File which should be read in with these 3 entries:

```
/dev/disk1s1
/dev/disk3s2
/dev/disk4s3
```

Every one of these 3 Entries should be "imported" as a Item into an existing  NSPopUpButton. In my case this delegated one:

```
@IBOutlet weak var testmenu: NSPopUpButton!
```

What are the next steps to create a dynamic Menu from the 3 dev-Lines above?

@El Tomato
Ok the Array is working. But don´t know how to add "drives" to the Outlet.

```
do {
    let file = try String(contentsOfFile: "/tmp/drives")
    let drives: [String] = file.components(separatedBy: "\n")
    print(drives)
} catch {
    Swift.print("Fatal Error: Couldn't read the contents!")
}
```

Comment: 1. Create an array out of those lines.  2. Set that array to your popup thing.

Comment: What does "add "drives" to the Outlet" mean?

Comment: It means the 3 /dev/diskxsx Values should be 3 Items in the NSPopUpButton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var popupButton: NSPopUpButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        popupButton.menu?.removeAllItems()

        // You should get this from your file
        let fileContent = """
        /dev/disk1s1
        /dev/disk3s2
        /dev/disk4s3
        """

        for (index, drive) in fileContent.components(separatedBy: "\n").enumerated() {
            popupButton.menu?.addItem(withTitle: drive, action: #selector(ViewController.menuItemClicked(_:)), keyEquivalent: "\(index + 1)")
        }
    }

    @objc func menuItemClicked(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
        print("\(sender.title) clicked")
    }
}
```

The `keyEquivalent` is the shortcut key for the menu item. If you don't want it, pass an empty string.

Comment: The Problem is that I can´t connect the NSpopButton to it. It simply don´t react if I drag and drop it.